# Golang time.Parse() Behavior - Dropping Precision when 000

Tags: parsing, datetime, go

In Go, I am confused as to the behavior of `time.Parse()` I observe when parsing date strings to `time.Time`.

In the event that a given time string's milliseconds are equal to exactly "000", e.g. "2017-01-02T01:02:03.000Z", `time.Parse()` will truncate the "000".

It would seem preferable to include, as opposed to omit this for consistency in logging and other use cases.

Is this the expected behavior? If so, why?

Bonus: How do we retain the "000"?

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RgjVSRKdIr)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    const (
        ISO_8601 = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z"
    )

    tMap := map[string]string{
        "t00": "2017-01-02T01:02:03.000Z",
        "t01": "2017-01-02T01:02:03.000Z",
        "t02": "2017-01-02T01:02:03.456Z",
        "t03": "2017-01-03T01:02:03.123Z",
        "t04": "2013-10-04T01:02:03.456Z",
        "t05": "2012-02-02T01:02:03.321Z",
        "t06": "2011-03-07T01:02:03.849Z",
    }

    for _, v := range tMap {
        t, err := time.Parse(ISO_8601, v)
        logFatal("0H N03Z!!1", err)

        // Dude where's my 000?
        log.Printf("Key: %s | lenTimeString: %d | Val: %s \n", t.String(), len(t.String()), t)
    }
}

func logFatal(hint string, e error) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal(hint, e)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Key: t05 | lenTimeString: 33 | timeString: 2012-02-02 01:02:03.321 +0000 UTC 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Key: t06 | lenTimeString: 33 | timeString: 2011-03-07 01:02:03.849 +0000 UTC 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Key: t00 | lenTimeString: 29 | timeString: 2017-01-02 01:02:03 +0000 UTC 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Key: t01 | lenTimeString: 29 | timeString: 2017-01-02 01:02:03 +0000 UTC 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Key: t02 | lenTimeString: 33 | timeString: 2017-01-02 01:02:03.456 +0000 UTC 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Key: t03 | lenTimeString: 33 | timeString: 2017-01-03 01:02:03.123 +0000 UTC 
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Key: t04 | lenTimeString: 33 | timeString: 2013-10-04 01:02:03.456 +0000 UTC
```

**Edit:** Here's a simplified solution with the kind help of @zerkms

[Play](https://play.golang.org/p/RgjVSRKdIr)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    p := fmt.Println

    const (
        ISO_8601           = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
        ISO_8601_dropmilli = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z"
    )

    t := time.Date(2017, time.October, 31, 15, 16, 17, 000000000, time.Local)

    p(t.Format(ISO_8601))
    p(t.Format(ISO_8601_dropmilli))
}
```

Output:

```
2017-10-31T15:16:17.000Z
2017-10-31T15:16:17Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.String` uses the `2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST` format.

To keep the zeroes use `0` instead of `9`: `2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000 -0700 MST`

```
t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 -0700 MST")
```

Comment: Thank you @zerkms. Would you be so kind as to illustrate this in an edit to the playground link I provided? I want to be crystal clear on how to apply your suggestion.

Comment: Thinking 'out loud', if we are converting time.Time to string, as opposed to string to time.Time then back to string, would the same use of 0 vs 9 work? TODO: post here once tested.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean :-)

Comment: What I mean here for any interested in this behavior: https://play.golang.org/p/RgjVSRKdIr